# Samsung Sensor Simulator

Tags: android, simulator, sensors, emulation

Has anyone any idea about the real-time aspect of Samsung Sensor Simulator(http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Sensor-Simulator)?
Their site does say indicate it's record-and-replay but not sure if I
get that right from their documentation. So, I have the below questions which
I have asked their forum as well. But, I am curios to know if anyone here
have tried it and have had some experiences to share.

1. Are the real hardware sensor readings of a linked device available
   on the Android emulator available in real-time? I saw it saying
   "Sensor Relay" which sounds like only record-and-replay of real
   hardware sensor readings on the emulator linked to a real device.
2. If it's real-time, then how fast are the sensor readings reaching
   from the linked device to the emulator?
3. Can any sensor-based application running on the emulator use these
   sensor readings in real-time?
4. In order to use these sensor readings, do the sensor-based
   applications need to be modified to include some extra specific code
   to interact with some module of this simulator inside the emulator
   from which the sensor readings are got and hence can be used within
   that interacting sensor-based application in the emulator?
5. Why is Samsung Sensor Simulator not compatible with Linux variants
   like Ubuntu?
6. Is it only compatible with Android 2.2 as it's mentioned in the
   documentation and not higher?
7. Android SDK must be of API 9 - is this a must or will it also work
   the latest API 19 but with some minor issues which can be ignored?
8. Can more than one sensor be active and be visualized in the eclipse
   IDE plugin interface? If yes, assuming any sensor-based application
   running on the emulator can use these sensor readings, can more than
   one sensor-based application use the different sensors readings at
   the same time in real-time?

Thanks,
Raghavan